# MATLAB travelling grids

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to built a "travelling grid" MATLAB. Actually, I had to choose another MATLAB command instead of `linspace` to built my grid for any `k`. Is it possible with a MATLAB command?

```
for k=1:5
    a=0;
    b(k)=k.*3;
    x=linspace(0,b(k),10);
    y=linspace(0,30,10);
    for z=1:length(x)
        for t=1:length(y)
            A(z,t,k)=x(z).*exp(-y(t)); 
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks for any help,

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  You have said that maybe `linspace` is inappropriate, but what is the aim of this matlab script?

Comment: I want to use for different k's different grids.In my example above, I tried to use for k=1 a grid between 0<x<b(1) and for k=2 0<x<b(2) etc.For simplicity I choosed a fixed grid on y.

Answer (score 2):

```
X = linspace(0,3,10);
XX(1,:,:) = bsxfun(@times,X,(1:5)')';
Y = exp(-linspace(0,30,10));
B = bsxfun(@times,Y',XX);
B = permute(B,[2,1,3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is working fine, so I'm not sure what the question is... Here is a slightly simpler implementation:

```
b = (1:5).*3;
A = zeros(10,10,5);
for k=1:5
    [X,Y] = ndgrid(linspace(0,b(k),10), linspace(0,30,10));
    A(:,:,k) = X.*exp(-Y);
end
```

If you also want the y-limits to change as well, the process is similar; you would have two loops and the result `A` being a 4D matrix